# How to create webform using conent editor in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am looking to insert contact from in my contacts page.

In the Content Editor, on the ribbon, on the Presentation tab, not showing  "Insert" button.

[image]

Is there any settings to appear this option ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like wffm wasn't installed correctly. Please check installation guide and verify log files.

Comment: Is your user member of the "Sitecore Client Forms Author" role?

Comment: installed "Web Forms For Marketers 8.1 Initial Version", now able to see the "Insert Form " button, but there is no any action when click that button.